# Flutter Firebase authentication - unlinking authentication provider does not result in the original (anonymous) user

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

After linking credentials (say, email and password, or Facebook) to an anonymous user, and then unlinking them, the resulting user (produced by the `userChanges` stream) has `email: null` (as I would expect), but `isAnonymous: false`, which I would not expect - the user has lost their anonymity. This is problematic if you subsequently only want to allow credentials to be (re-)linked against an anonymous user.

`userChanges` also contradicts the Firebase console, in which the user identifier remains the email address from the linked credential, instead of reverting back to `(anonymous)` - this, despite the `email: null` from the stream.

Is the above the intended behaviour?

Comment: Why would you expect the account remain anonymous after linking it with a known account?  The whole point of linking an account is to attach an identity, and allow the user to effectively "upgrade" their anonymous account (which could have been created without them knowing) into a fully privileged account.  If you want an account to remain truly anonymous, you should not link anything to it.

Comment: @DougStevenson As I stated, the problem occurs after linking and then _unlinking_ the credential.

Comment: There's nothing in the documentation that suggests unlinking an account is effectively a downgrade to anonymous.  This could have privacy implications for the end user, especially in the EU.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sure. But I find the resulting ```userChanges``` stream and Firebase console states confusing: the stream tells me the user does not have an email nor any ```providerData```, and that - despite this - the user is not anonymous. Which makes me wonder what it means for the user to be anonymous. And at the same time, the Firebase console tells me the user is identifiable by the email from the _unlinked_ credential.

Comment: If you have feedback about the console, contact Firebase support to explain what you find confusing.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior: once the `isAnonymous` flag becomes `false`, it won't become `true` again after unlinking the additional providers.

If you'd like to detect this situation, you can check whether the user has any providers in its `providerData` array.

For example, this is how one of my apps checks whether the user is signed in with a Google account:

```
  bool isSignedInUser() {
    return this.user != null && (
      this.user.providerData.any((UserInfo info) => info.providerId == "google.com")
    );
  }
```

You'll need something different, but I hope this code gives you a good starting point.